# How to fire up Scala interpreter with ScalaCheck in the classpath in Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: scala, scalacheck

Scala is installed and working fine.
scalacheck.jar is placed in the /bin .
I used the following command

```
$ scala -cp scalacheck.jar
```

After that, when i tried the below command,

```
scala> import org.scalacheck.Prop.forAll
```

I got the following error.

```
<console>:7: error: object scalacheck is not a member of package org
   import org.scalacheck.Properties
              ^
```

I might have done some mistake in using scalacheck, please correct me and give the proper commands so that I can able to work with scalacheck in Ubuntu in interpreter mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting executable on the path isn't the same as jar being on the classpath, so your jar being in `/bin` didn't change anything.

Just use:

```
scala -cp path_to_your.jar
```

and you should be fine.

If for example, your `scalachek.jar` is in `/bin` then use:

```
scala -cp /bin/scalacheck.jar
```

**edit:**

Putting jars in `/bin` probably isn't the best idea.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response and for the solution. Its working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use it like this:

```
kjozsa@walrus:~$ scala -version
Scala code runner version 2.9.2 -- Copyright 2002-2011, LAMP/EPFL
kjozsa@walrus:~$ locate scalacheck.jar
/usr/share/scala/lib/scalacheck.jar
kjozsa@walrus:~$ scala -cp /usr/share/scala/lib/scalacheck.jar
Welcome to Scala version 2.9.2 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_03-icedtea).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> import org.scalacheck.Prop.forAll
import org.scalacheck.Prop.forAll

scala>
```